# Change name of content type for faceting

Tags: solr, typo3, facet

I use the following TS from documentation (apache-solr-for-typo3) for a simple facet

```
plugin.tx_solr.search {
    faceting = 1
    faceting {
        facets {
            contentType {
                label = Content Type
                field = type
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The result is e.g.

```
sys_file_metadata (691)
tt_address (341)
tx_news_domain_model_news (180)
pages (153)
tx_events2_domain_model_event (2)
```

How can I rename e.g. `tt_address` to `Personen` and the other titles for better readability?

Here is my configuration for `tt_address`

```
plugin.tx_solr.index.queue {
    tt_address = 1
    tt_address {
        table = tt_address
        lable = Personen

        additionalWhereClause = first_name NOT LIKE ''

        fields {
            abstract = position
            description = description
            title = name
            personen_stringS = Personen

            content = SOLR_CONTENT
            content {
                field = title
            }
            url = TEXT
            url {
                typolink.parameter.field = detail
                typolink.returnLast = url
                typolink.useCacheHash = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

TYPO3 10.4.18., solr 11.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not at the queuing where you set the **label**.

```
plugin {
    tx_solr {
        search {
            faceting = 1
            faceting {
                facets {
#                contentType {
#                    label = Content Type
#                    field = type
#                }
                    contentType {
                        label = Filter
                        field = type

                        renderingInstruction = CASE
                        renderingInstruction {
                            key.field = optionValue

                            pages = TEXT
                            pages.value = Internetseiten

                            tx_solr_file = TEXT
                            tx_solr_file.value = Dateien

                            tx_news_domain_model_news = TEXT
                            tx_news_domain_model_news.value = Nachrichten

                            tt_address = TEXT
                            tt_address.value = Adressen
                        }
                   }
               :
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help.